# Работаю в FastReport с помощью функции Case в SQL

Tags: sql, fastreport

> Error Required Param value not set

Code:

```
SELECT id_vst, 
       CASE  
           WHEN id_sys = 155 THEN CAST('Visible' AS varchar(80))  
           ELSE CAST(' ' AS varchar(80))  
       END AS result 
FROM DOC_ACC_CNT
```

Comment: Не, а вопрос-то какой? И да, если что - это ошибка именно FastReport, а не SQL...

Comment: Вопрос в том как решить именно эту ошибку, почему она появилась и где мне надо что-то сделать что исправить ?

Comment: Ну вроде вменяемо пишут - требуемый (обязательный, вероятно) параметр не установлен. В коде FR, ясен пень. А кода FR в вопросе нет, ну от слова "совсем". А у нас ХШ в ремонте, и догадаться, какой код приводит к ошибке, и какой параметр не задан - без шансов.